# How to get a link to change innerHTML more than once in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I am trying to get a link to change javascript innerHTML everytime it is clicked.

```
function id_1(a){
    var id = document.getElementById(a);
    if (id.innerHTML==="innerHTML2"){
        id.innerHTML="innerHTML1";
    }
    if (id.innerHTML==="innerHTML1"){
        id.innerHTML="innerHTML2";
    }
}
```

```
<a id="id" href="javascript:id_1('id')">innerHTML1</a>
```

I want it to change from `innerHTML1` to `innerHTML2` to `innerHTML1` to `innerHTML2` and so on as you click the link.

Right now it is only switching one time from `innerHTML1` to `innerHTML2`

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `else if` for the second if statement.

The logic in your code works like the following on the second click (when the content is innerHTML2):

1. The first if statement tests if the content is innerHTML2, it is so the content is changed to innerHTML1 (what you wanted).
2. The second if statement test if the content is innerHTML1, it is (since it was just changed at step 1) so the content is changed back to innerHTML1 (not what you wanted).

So the solution should look like the following:

```
function id_1(a){
    var id = document.getElementById(a); 
    if (id.innerHTML=="innerHTML2"){
        id.innerHTML="innerHTML1";
    }else if (id.innerHTML=="innerHTML1"){
        id.innerHTML="innerHTML2";
    }
}
```

To emphasize the point you could keep the code the same way but use return to make sure that only one if statement is used.

```
function id_1(a){
    var id = document.getElementById(a); 
    if (id.innerHTML=="innerHTML2"){
        id.innerHTML="innerHTML1";
        return;
    }

    if (id.innerHTML=="innerHTML1"){
        id.innerHTML="innerHTML2";
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to use an `else` between your `if` statements:

```
function id_1(a){
    var id = document.getElementById(a);
    if (id.innerHTML==="innerHTML2"){
        id.innerHTML="innerHTML1";
    } else if (id.innerHTML==="innerHTML1"){
        id.innerHTML="innerHTML2";
    }
}
```

Without the `else` your second `if` is impacted by changes made in the first `if`.

Since the innerHTML has only two states, you could actually simplify to:

```
function id_1(a){
    var id = document.getElementById(a);
    if (id.innerHTML==="innerHTML2"){
        id.innerHTML="innerHTML1";
    } else {
        id.innerHTML="innerHTML2";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing an else:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function id_1(a){
    var id = document.getElementById(a);
    if (id.innerHTML==="innerHTML2"){
        id.innerHTML="innerHTML1";
    }
    else if (id.innerHTML==="innerHTML1"){
        id.innerHTML="innerHTML2";
    }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="id" href="javascript:id_1('id')">innerHTML1</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WCgAS/

Answer (score 1):

It actually is swithing all the times, but as you have it written, it switches to "innerHTML1"  and then right back to "innerHTML2"

so just change the second "if" to "else if"

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function id_1(a){
    var id = document.getElementById(a);
    if (id.innerHTML==="innerHTML2"){
    id.innerHTML="innerHTML1";
    }
    else if (id.innerHTML==="innerHTML1"){
    id.innerHTML="innerHTML2";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="id" href="javascript:id_1('id')">innerHTML1</a>
</body>
</html>
```